# Access an alias-Directory

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I like to access this folder

```
 Alias  "/dataBox" "/var/www/vhosts/myDomain.de/folder1/folder2/files"
```

with php by another document-root.

By adding this...

```
<Location /dataBox>
   Options +Indexes
</Location>
```

...to my httpd.conf I'm able to access the folders content over the browser in a apache generated filelist.

But when I try to access this file like ...

```
$filename = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/dataBox/cache/12345-boy-872666';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

... this, it only returns:

```
The file /var/www/vhosts/myDomain.de/folder1/folder2/dataBox/cache/filename.txt does not exist
```

Later, the folder wouldn't be browseable with the option `+Indexes`

How can I access this folder?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a local file-system access, which has absolutely **NO** knowledge of Apache configuration. You need to do a (highly-inefficient) full-blown HTTP request:

```
file_exists('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/databox/etc....');
```

You'd be FAR better using the actual real path locally, or at least creating a symlink at the filesystem level. Such things will be transparent to both Apache and PHP, without having to involve the http layer just to check if a file exists.

Comment: Yes, but I want to lock the directory with .htaccess-file, so an http request wouldn't work?! The file should only be accessable over php, and NOT http

Comment: then don't put it into your document root. if you don't want something accessible to the outside world, you DON'T put it somewhere where by definition it IS accessible to the outside world.